# How to insert Spotlight for Help into localized macOS applications?

Tags: java, macos, swing, localization, spotlight

I am implementing a Java application using the Swing GUI framework on macOS. When using the *system* look and feel and a *screen* menu bar, Swing automatically inserts a *search field* called [Spotlight for Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/user_help_concepts/apple_help_concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH205-BABBDDJC) into the first menu labelled `"Help"` of the menu bar of a frame:

[image: Help menu with search feature]

```java
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");

try {
  UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
menuBar.add(helpMenu);
frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

As my application is localized, the English string `"Help"` is different in other locales (e.g. `"Aide"` in French). But in those cases Swing does not insert Spotlight for Help since the string is different:

[image: Help menu without search feature]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

1. [Bundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) the `.class` files and resources (image, sound, video, localization files, etc.) of your application in a `.jar` file with Oracle's [Java Archive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html).
2. [Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806709/application-is-using-java-6-from-apple-instead-of-java-7-from-oracle-on-mac-os-x/15271448#15271448) your `.jar` file in an `.app` directory with Oracle's [AppBundler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) (for Java 7+, which replaces the old Apple's [JarBundler](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001885-208447) for Java 6).
3. Add to the `.app` directory the `Contents/Resources/<locale>.lproj` directories for each locale that should be supported by your application (you can let the locale directories empty since the localization files can be already in the `.jar` file).
4. Launch your application (double-click on the application icon in Finder or type `open <application>.app` in Terminal).

The search field Spotlight for Help will appear.

## Explanation

*I'm going to make a guess and it's that you're executing the `.class` files directly (from an IDE, for instance) or the `.jar` file, because from what I know this should be working.*

Although what most sources say, Swing is deeply rooted on system calls and thus relies on the OS for many features, like in this case. Ideally, this should be covered by the method [`setHelpMenu(JMenu)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuBar.html#setHelpMenu-javax.swing.JMenu-) but as you'll notice [this has never been implemented](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4087846).

If you check first, you'll notice that there's no extra component added in your [`JMenuBar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuBar.html) and you have no control over that. If you try using AWT's [`MenuBar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/MenuBar.html) instead you'll see the behavior is exactly the same although, insterestingly enough, the method [`setHelpMenu(Menu)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/MenuBar.html#setHelpMenu-java.awt.Menu-) it is really implemented but doesn't add the search field if the menu is named something different from `"Help"`.

At this point I found a workaround and it's setting the menu label to `"Help"` and once displayed (don't use [`ComponentListener.componentShown(ComponentEvent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentShown-java.awt.event.ComponentEvent-), this won't work, use [`AncestorListener.ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/AncestorListener.html#ancestorAdded-javax.swing.event.AncestorEvent-)) changing the menu label to the localized one. This will add the search field to the help menu. However the search field will in English, with the label `"Search"`.

Checking the API, it's more than clear that in Swing this feature is [not implemented](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/laf/ScreenMenuBar.java) and fully relies on AWT. AWT on the other hand has [partly implemented](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/macosx/native/sun/awt/CMenuBar.m) the native calls to the OS, but [it's not wired to be invokable](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/eawt/_AppMenuBarHandler.java). Reaching this point and knowing that the search field does appear in our application and that in other ones running in Java it's properly localized lets us hint that this is a trait of the OS itself (I might be wrong at this point and it's really AWT doing the dirty job, but wasn't able to find any piece of code that does it directly, although in Objective C you can define any).

Reading the documentation about [how to localize a Java application in MacOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001885-208447), we note that:

- it's a requirement that the application be bundled in an `.app` directory and contain the `Contents/Resources/<os-locale>.lproj` directory, so that the OS recognizes the OS locale as supported by the application, and consequently expects a menu labeled with the *OS-localized* `"Help"` string in order to add the OS-localized search field to that menu;
- otherwise, the OS treats the application as `en_US` localized, and consequently expects a menu labeled with the `en_US`-localized `"Help"` string in order to add the `en_US`-localized search field to that menu.

Now you can type `open <application>.app` in Terminal and your application will be launched with the OS-localized search field added to the help menu.

Note that Apple has its own mechanism for forcing the application to use another locale than the OS locale, and it's using the `-AppleLanguages` option (`open <application>.app --args -AppleLanguages "(<locale>)"`). The [Language Switcher](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/) utility does the same under the hood. Again, the appropriate `Contents/Resources/<locale>.lproj` directory should exist, otherwise the OS will treat the application as `en_US` localized.

How you [make an `.app` directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) from the `.class` files and resources (image, sound, video, localization files, etc.) of your application is beyond the scope of this question because it varies depending on the platform you're using, but Oracle provides the [Java Archive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) (to make the intermediary `.jar` file) and [AppBundler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) (to make the `.app` directory) utilities.

**Screenshot**

[image: Localized search field]

The OS is localized in Spanish in this screenshot but the application is localized in French, because it's been launched with the `-AppleLanguages "(fr)"` option.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks. I edited your answer that suggests to use Apple's JarBundler (for Java 6) because it is a legacy program that has been replaced by Oracle's AppBundler (for Java 7+).

Comment: That's great, good to know about AppBundler. You also removed the part where's explained why running classes directly doesn't show locales other than `en_US` and I find it important to understand what's happening under the hood initially. Anyway, I leave it up to you since if you feel answered, who am I to contradict you.

Comment: I found your sentence "Java is defined to only work with the language `en_US`" ambiguous and so did not understand your last paragraph, that is why I removed it in the first place. But now I know what you meant: macOS assumes the locale is `en_US` (and consequently expects a menu labelled with the English string `"Help"`, in which it can add the Spotlight field) when there is no `<application>.app` bundle containing a directory named `Contents/Resources/<locale>.lproj`. I have improved the answer accordingly. Again, thank you for this complete answer.

Comment: I have just found out another way (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

I have just found out another way. No need to add empty `Contents/Resources/<locale>.lproj` directories in the `.app` directory, just adding these two lines (key-value pair) in the `Contents/Info.plist` file of the `.app` directory works:

```
<key>CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations</key>
<true />
```

And the new way to make an `.app` bundle is to use Oracle's [JavaPackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html) command-line utility, which is part of the J.D.K. It generates an `.app` directory with a `Contents/Info.plist` that has the above two lines by default (no need to pass the key-value pair as an option of `javapackager` in the command-line). And forcing another locale with the `open <application>.app --args -AppleLanguages "(<locale>)"` command *really* works with the `<application>.app` directory generated by Oracle's JavaPackager, contrary to the one generated by Oracle's AppBundler.

Comment: I remember trying this at some point but didn't work for me, but indeed works. About the JavaPackager, if you check my original response I deliberately left out the different tools available, explained the issue and just made some suggestions to have a look at (I use a Maven plugin for instance), because each one has their own particularities. That's why I don't like heavy edits, but as long as the community approves, I'm fine.